# Changing development URL to Production in client proxy

Tags: c#, web-services, proxy, load-balancing, web-reference

I have consumed a web service running behind load balancer using add services in vs2008 and it was exposed the URL to app config but it is not the web service URL but the load balancer url.

Now I am having a problem that when we are moving it to production I only need to add the web service URL not the load balncer URL. Load balancer URL was automatically added by VS2008.
Pls let know how to change the URL when we moving to production.

Comment: What happens if you just change it in the config file?

Comment: It needs only the loadbalancer URLif i provide the web service URL it is not working.